# Load Spring bean

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way in Spring to load a bean specifically.

I've a appContext file having lots of beans.
When loading it using the following code, it loads all beans again.

```
BeanFactory factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");
```

Comment: Why would you want to recreate a context?

Comment: I'm in a quartz job class and need a bean object there, which calls a dao class.(Application is running in tomcat server and this class will get executed in every 30 mins)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using `ApplicationContextAware`?

Bean mapping

`<bean id="springApplicationContext" class="SpringApplicationContext"/>`

**Java implementation**

```
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = ctx;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String name) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

**Then use it like this;**

`SpringApplicationContext.getBean("myBean");`

Comment: This is also useful if you want to call a Spring bean from legacy code, such as from an EJB layer.

Answer (score 2):

By default, spring creates instances of all `singleton`-scoped beans at startup.

I would recommend you to split you spring configuration in several distinct files. In that case you'll be able to load only that group of beans which is required for your task.

Another way is to declare your beans with `default-lazy-init` attribute:

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
    <!-- no beans will be pre-instantiated... -->
</beans>
```

Comment: What will be the code to retrieve the bean from this xml. will it be same as given in my question? I need only the given bean loaded.

Comment: @Joe: what prevents you from trying? The same code should still work (something like `beanFactory.getBean(name, clazz)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApplicationContextAware interface. 
[example](http://jerlinworld.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/making-your-spring-application-context-aware/)

When you get instance of this bean, you can load whatever bean you want.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to migrate to using springs abstraction of quartz. That way, your quartz "jobs" are spring beans from the start.

Read more [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html).

Answer (score 0):

This may help in order to avoid having to recreate a spring context.

If you use [Spring to configure the quartz job](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) then you can reference spring beans directly from your job.

For example, if you use the [MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.html), then you could create a bean that executes the code, which in turn calls your DAO.

```
<bean id="exampleBusinessObject" class="my.pkg.BusinessObject">
    <property name="dao" ref="myDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="exampleJob"  
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="exampleBusinessObject"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="doIt"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="exampleJob" />
    <!-- run every 30 min -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/30 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```